# Django + form for resetting the password

Tags: python, django

I wanted to create a form for resetting the user's password. It should take the `current_password`, and then the `new_password` and `confirm_new_password`. I'm able to do the validation to check the new passwords are matching. How would I be able to validate the `current_password`? Is there a way to pass in the `User` object into the form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django comes with a built in `PasswordChangeForm` that you can import and use in your view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
```

But you don't even have to write your own password reset view. There is a pair of views [`django.contrib.with.views.password_change`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_change) and `django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done`, that you can hook straight into your URL config.

Comment: For my purposes this wouldn't work. Since i'm combining the password reset within a form that includes many other things. But this would be the correct way for this use case.

Comment: @KVISH I know this is a very late comment but for the record, you can display and process more than one Django Form inside an HTML `<form>`. There are few reasons you couldn't use `PasswordChangeForm` alongside another form for your other changes.

Answer (score 0):

Found a really good example of this: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/158/

**[EDIT]**

I used the above link and made a few changes. They are here below:

```
class PasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False)
    current_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(PasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_current_password(self):
        # If the user entered the current password, make sure it's right
        if self.cleaned_data['current_password'] and not self.user.check_password(self.cleaned_data['current_password']):
            raise ValidationError('This is not your current password. Please try again.')

        # If the user entered the current password, make sure they entered the new passwords as well
        if self.cleaned_data['current_password'] and not (self.cleaned_data['password'] or self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']):
            raise ValidationError('Please enter a new password and a confirmation to update.')

        return self.cleaned_data['current_password']

    def clean_confirm_password(self):
        # Make sure the new password and confirmation match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')

        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your passwords didn't match. Please try again.")

        return self.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')
```